# Explode rows pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-explode

I have a pandas dataframe like the below:

| Letters | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 'Letters : a' | 2021 |
| 'Letters : a,b,c' | 2019 |
| 'Letters : a,b' | 2017 |

I want to be turned into the below, using pandas/python.

| Letters | Date |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2021 |
| a | 2019 |
| b | 2019 |
| c | 2019 |
| a | 2017 |
| b | 2017 |

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your rows are really formatted like this `'Letters : a,b,c'`? (with quotes)

Comment: No need to worry about the quotes i've entered them just to show that it is a string.

Comment: Ok so the values are `a,b,c` without Letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to parse out the relevant information in to a `list` prior to using `explode`.

```
df.assign(
    Letters=df.Letters \
              .str \
              .split(" : ", expand=True)[1] \
              .str.split(",") \
         ) \
  .explode("Letters")

  Letters  Date
0       a  2021
1       a  2019
1       b  2019
1       c  2019
2       a  2017
2       b  2017
```

Please note the index is not reset in this answer, you can do that if you need by calling `reset_index`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode` after `split` your values:

```
>>> df.assign(Letters=df['Letters'].str.split(',')).explode('Letters')

  Letters  Date
0       a  2021
1       a  2019
1       b  2019
1       c  2019
2       a  2017
2       b  2017
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows

Comment: Why again dupe?

Comment: It is many times answered, so why not closed?

Comment: Apologies ,just wanted an extra mile with the split(" : ", expand=True)[1] step that @gold_cy provided.